# Javascript tags to Jquery Switch statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made script tags that serves as the event holder when a button is click this events are triggered.The setup is like this: I have 6 buttons and I made that six times from btn1 to btn6.

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="AUS">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var shade = document.getElementById('shade');

    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
        var src = "img2/Australia.jpg";
        var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
        img.src = src;
        img.style.display = "inline";
        modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'block';
    };

    document.getElementById('close2').onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'none';
    };
</script>
```

After I finished I noticed they are working however there are instances that they cease to function, my friend suggested to me, "what if you use a Jquery Switch statement?". Here's what I come up with but I can't make it to work if you can help me to point out my mistake. I would be very grateful.

Jquery Code:

```
$('.sbutton').on('click', function () {
    switch (this.val()) {
    case 'btn1':
        var src = "img2/Australia.jpg";
        var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
        img.src = src;
        img.style.display = "inline";
        modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'block';
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler, `this` is a native DOM element.

Change

```
switch (this.val()) {
```

to

```
switch ($(this).val()) {
```

or (better)

```
switch (this.value) {
```

But you should have seen an error in the console. Please read [Using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).